# How to add punchin time and actual time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time, jquery-validate

I have two time,punchin time and actual time.
The get out time is the sum of these two.
You can see my code on http://jsfiddle.net/FHhDQ/5/

```
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        var sum = 0;

        var intime=$('#intime').val();
        var outtime=$('#brktime').val();
        alert(intime);
        var actualtime='08:00';
        var result = add(intime, actualtime);
        alert(actualtime);
        alert(result);
        $('#result').val(result);
        });
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to add these two time?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this dirty way of parsing times using Date.parse:

```
function timeToDate(time) { 
    return Date.parse('1970-01-01 ' + time + ' UTC'); 
}

var date = new Date(timeToDate('08:00') + timeToDate('02:34'));
date.getHours()   // 11
date.getMinutes() // 34
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that stuff directly like that.

You have to use couple of functions for validations.

Here you can find adding N number of timings

[How to get of two time values using jQuery/Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285172/how-to-get-of-two-time-values-using-jquery-javascript)